# wrapping operations in a python decorator

Tags: python

I've written a [python library](https://github.com/astex/needs) that allows users to create objects with logical operators tied to them that can then be used as decorators.  For example:

```
edit_need = owner_need | admin_need

@edit_need
def edit():
    # Raise an error if the need is not met.
```

It would be nice to shorten this to:

```
@(owner_need | admin_need)
def edit():
    # ...
```

Of course this raises a syntax error.  The same thing can be accomplished with an additional decorator such as:

```
def decorator(dec):
    @wraps(dec)
    def adapt(f):
        return dec(f)
    return adapt

@decorator(owner_need | admin_need)
def edit():
    # ...
```

But, this feels like something there is a python built-in for.  I haven't been able to find it with a casual googling, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for here?  As you've discovered, [decorators only take `dotted_name`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) (e.g. `foo` or `foo.bar`), not expressions.  The function which returns a decorator is valid syntax, but you've already discovered that too . . .Are you looking for suggestions on how else it might be done?  That seems like it might be very close to off-topic :-)

Comment: If you read the last part of the question, I'm asking for a python built-in that does the same thing as `decorator()` or something similar.  Since that is a question about the basic tools of the language itself, rather than methodology within the language, I thought it would be on-topic.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Well, I don't think that there's any builtin for this ... There are too many variations and (as you've demonstrated), it's a pretty straight forward 5-line function so I think it's probably not worth it.

Comment: IMHO, Python's built-ins are full of small <5 line wrappers that allow you to do quite a bit.  For example, @wraps above is a one-line built-in function.  Since there are quite a few places someone might want to use operators in decorators (or just wrap their decorator to explicitly declare it is a decorator), it feels like there might be one.

Comment: To be fair, what you're talking about is a 2-liner:  `def decorator(dec): return dec`  (or a 1-line lambda).  Basically, all you want is the identity function.  I think that the identity function isn't included in the standard library because python doesn't want to be a functional programming language.  I've gotten the impression that Guido regrets the limited support that it has (`filter`, `map`, `lambda`, etc.).  Anyway, if you feel strongly about it, feel free to post an idea on [python-ideas](https://www.python.org/community/lists/#python-ideas-mailing-list)  :-)